# Recursive function to sort an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm having trouble building a recursive function that sorts an integer array. At this point, I don't know any sorting algorithms, this is only my second CS course. I've seen a lot of solutions on here, but the issue with those solutions is that they have loops or nested conditions statements. In this function I cannot use loops or nested if statements, only single if/else statements.

I know you guys don't want to simply give answers since it takes away from the learning experience, but if I could just get pointed in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Merge sort is a sort that takes advantage of the fact that an array of one element is sorted.

Comment: These type of programming are called DP ( Dynamic Programming). And Quick sort is the fastest sorting algorithm (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-quick-sort/) explains the basics..

Comment: [Quicksort ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is the canonical example of a recursive sorting algorithm.

Comment: I'd recommend not looking at the existing algorithms until they ask you to.  Start with your base case.  The size of the array is expected to reach 1, meaning the previous call was provided an array of a larger size.  So it's best to try for yourself first, to find how an array might be sorted in a way that involves looking at increasingly smaller sections of it.  Use what you've learned about  recursion to deduce what you may do before and after calling the function.  Use physical or drawn objects to aid in finding a working solution. This will help you understand many algorithms easily later

Answer (score 4):

To write a recursive function-

1. Write a function signature and assume that it will do your job with some magic.
2. Now think about base condition i.e what will your function do in case of smallest valid input.
3. Now write the induction step in which you call the same function on smaller input(generally).

   ```
   def sorting(arr):

       #Base Condition
       if len(arr) == 1:
           return

       #Induction
       last_num = arr[-1]
       arr.pop()
       sorting(arr)
       insert(arr, last_num)

       return arr

   def insert(arr, last_num):

       #Base Condition
       if len(arr) == 0 or arr[-1] <= last_num:
           arr.append(last_num)
           return

       #Induction
       val = arr[-1]
       arr.pop()
       insert(arr, last_num)
       arr.append(val)
   ```

Comment: Just to give a name to this for those who may be curious, this is essentially [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) done recursively. Passing an index is probably cleaner and faster than chopping off and re-appending the tail of the list. This program crashes when called with an empty list. I'd use `len(arr) <= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) which is a recursive algorithm that will do exactly what you need. Let me know if you need help implementing it.

Comment: For beginners, I think QuickSort is too difficult. InsertionSort/SelectionSort/BubbleSort are much easier for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have heard about divide and conquer algorithm, where we divide the given array with respect to a particular element, known as 'pivot' such that the lower partition of the array are less than the pivot and upper partition elements of the array are higher than the pivot. Quicksort is one of the best example of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of simpliest algorithms, just add recursive call. E.g. this is algorithm close to *InsertinSort*. At each step, we look thorugh array up to `hi`, and `swap` current element with highest in case of current element is greater than highest one. At the end for each loop, `hi` posint to the start of arra, that is sortered:

```
public final class BubbleSort {

    public static void sort(int[] arr) {
        sort(arr, arr.length);
    }

    private static void sort(int[] arr, int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (arr[i] > arr[n - 1])
                    swap(arr, i, n - 1);

            sort(arr, n - 1);
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }

    private SelectionSort() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer in  c++ Program

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void insert(std::vector<int> &v,int num)
{
    if(v.size()==0 || v[v.size()-1]<=num)
    {
        v.push_back(num);
        return ;
    }
    int num2=v.back();
    v.pop_back();
    insert(v,num);
    v.push_back(num2);

}


void  sortv(vector<int> &v)
{
    if(v.size()==1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int num=v.back();
    v.pop_back();
    sortv(v);
    insert(v,num);

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v={1,4,3,5,6,7,1,2,3};
    sortv(v);
    for (auto i : v) {
       cout<<i<<" ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Of Course there are merge sort and quick sort which use recursion and are among the best known sorting algorithms. Since you are a beginner it would be better if you start with relatively simpler ones. Here is the selection sort algorithm that uses recursion.

```
int selection_sort(int num[], int n) //n=array length
{
    int max = num[0];   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (num[i] > max) 
            max = num[i];
        num[i] = num[n - 1];
        num[n - 1] = max;       
    }

    if (n > 0) {
        selection_sort(num, n - 1);
    }
}
```